# Node.js Buffer.from() throws TypeError exception

Tags: node.js

```js
    // Construct the message
    var msg = 'Your payment of' + (orderData.paymentIntent.amount / 100) + '$ for the order with order ID ' + orderData.id + ' has been received successfully';

    // Configure the request payload
    var payload = {
        'from' : 'Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@SANDBOXDOMAIN.mailgun.org>',
        'to' : 'MAILADDRESS',
        'subject' : 'Order Receipt For Order ID: ' + orderData.id,
        'html' : msg
    };

    // Stringify the payload
    var stringPayload = querystring.stringify(payload);

    // Configure the request details
    var requestDetails = {
      'protocol' : 'https:',
      'hostname' : 'api.mailgun.net',
      'method' : 'POST',
      'path' : '/v3/SANDBOXDOMAIN.mailgun.org/messages',
      'auth' : {
      'username' : 'api',
      'password' : 'API_KEY'
      },
      'headers' : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length' : Buffer.byteLength(stringPayload)
      }
    };
```

Hi! I have been trying to write a function to send mail via Mailgun and I've sort of hit a wall. The above code, whenever I test it out, throws an invalid type error which says:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received an instance of Object
```

Oddly enough when I take out the `auth` object (or just set it up so that it isn't an object), my code works. I can't really understand why though. I haven't used any external libraries, this is just Node.js and since I'm new to Node I couldn't figure it out on my own. Any help is appreciated so thank you in advance.

Edit: I tested the code again and apparently the above code works fine but when I create a request object like so:

```js
    // Instantiate the request object
    var req = https.request(requestDetails, function(res){
      // Grab the status of the sent request
      var status = res.statusCode;

      // Callback successfully if the request went through
      if(status == 200) {
        callback(false);
      } else {
        callback('Status code returned was ' + status);
      }
    });
```

buffer.js throws the TypeError. I discovered that the error is thrown from Buffer.from() function at buffer.js line 333. I still can't understand why this happens though. It just doesn't make sense to me how `auth` being an object containing properties can cause this error to get thrown since, like I mentioned, making `auth` a simple property fixes the issue (but then of course I get a 401 status code after sending the request meaning I wasn't authorized)

Comment: It seems ' 'from' : 'Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@SANDBOXDOMAIN.mailgun.org>'" is not a valid email address. Can you add more description about the error message?

Comment: I'm aware that it isn't valid but since SANDBOXDOMAIN is actually the domain ,which contains my API key that is provided when you sign up to Mailgun, I didn't think it would be right for me to specify that here. Same thing with the 'auth' : { 'username' : 'api', 'password' : 'API_KEY' }. But if you mean that the format of the email address is invalid, I was just copying the Mailgun API docs so I'm not really sure whether if that is correct or not. Hopefully I can find out once I figure out how to get rid of the TypeError @ApoorvaChikara